# ASP.NET Controls and Generics

Tags: asp.net, generics, user-controls

can ASP.NET controls be used with generics? Never seen this done and want a way to differentiate some controls on a page by type, ie: **DateTime** vs **int**

example:

```
public class MyGenericTextBox<T>: TextBox
{
public MyGenericTextBox<T>() {... }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it and run into an error or are you just curious? If curious, why not try it?

Comment: Thinking best practices, not so much compiler compliance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a special hack, for example the one I used in this article:

[A Typed Repeater in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TypedRepeater.aspx)

However I would not recommend doing this just for convenience in simple cases, since the result would be more complex than the thing you'll try to improve.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful - Visual Studio cannot create intellisense schemas when one of the classes in an assembly of controls is generic.  Someone added a control like this to one of our projects and it took us two months to figure out why we had no intellisense in our markup.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably work if you only used the control from code.  I doubt it could be represented in markup or in the designer.